# highcharts - remove "margin" and change the gitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

First of, please check this picture:

[image]

As you can see, left from "Today" and right from "26-03", there is some 'margin' or 'padding' of some kind. 
How can I do, so my chart starts from the beginning and end at the complete end, without this space?
M

My second question is, how can I change the "gitter" color, and the width in the background?

Thanks i advance.

Comment: your second question is not clear. Can you rephrase or explain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for startOnTick and endOnTick option.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/startontick-true/